# Как написать в официальном документе: "Открыт счет на имя Иванова" или "Открыт счет Иванову"?

Tags: редактура, документы

Как правильно написать фразу в официальном документе:

> В Инвестбанке" на имя Иванова Ивана Ивановича открыты счета №№...

или

> В Инвестбанке" Иванову Ивану Ивановичу открыты счета №№...

Или обе фразы верны?
Если отталкиваться от английского языка (account held in the name of), то первая фраза корректнее.
Как же правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Вы правы, первая фраза корректна, вторая разговорная, потому что счёт открывают не кому-то, а на чьё-то имя. Значение фразы "Вам открыт счёт" несколько другое: вам открыт доступ к счёту. Он может быть и не ваш.

Answer (score 0):

"Сделать что-л. Иванову" может иметь смысл "сделать что-л. для Иванова", например Иванову построили дом, Иванову открыли счет в банке. Но это разговорный стиль, для официального документа не подходит.